# Does a const return type inhibit RVO/moving?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

[Somewhat related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089730/why-would-const-ness-of-a-local-variable-inhibit-move-semantics-for-the-returned), I have a question about returning `const` and how that affects RVO and moving. I typically like to make my functions return `const` objects like so:

```
// Return const to help ensure the potential temporary can't be used incorrectly
const std::vector<int> foo()
{
    std::vector<int> bar(10, 42); // Note: this is not const
    return bar;
}
```

Now I have a question about how this affects RVO and moving. If I do the following:

```
std::vector<int> myVector = foo();
```

Will the `const`-ness of `foo`'s return type inhibit RVO or moving? Even if the local variable in `foo` itself is not `const`? If I want to take advantage of RVO and move semantics, should I get rid of the `const`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16834937/819272 for why const return is not a good idea in C++11 (it inhibits move semantics)

Comment: @TemplateRex: wow, that was very informative; pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Or another related: [Should I still return const objects in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13099942/341970)