# Returning const values to leverage move semantics vs preventing stuff like (a+b)=c

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, move-semantics

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138780/move-semantics-returning-const-values) was slightly misunderstood.

Returning `const` values is not something that can be dismissed as meaningless. As Adam Burry pointed out in a comment, Scott Meyers recommends it in *More Effective C++* (Item 6), to which I would add Herb Sutter's *Exceptional C++* (Item 20, Class Mechanics, whose corresponding GotW is [available online](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/004.htm)).

The rationale for doing this is that you want the compiler to catch typos like `(a+b)=c` (oops, meant `==`), or misleading statements like `a++++`, both of which are flagged out-of-the-box for primitive types like `int`. So for stuff like `operator+` and `operator++(int)`, returning a `const` value does make sense.

On the other hand, as has been pointed out, returning a `const` prevents C++11's move semantics from kicking in, because they require a *non-*`const` rvalue reference.

So my question is, can we really not have our cake and eat it? (I couldn't find a way.)

Comment: I think the "advantage" of returning `const` has been over-stated before. Changing the semantics of a function just to avoid some possible typo seems like overkill. So I would say, you don't even want to eat the cake, it isn't a very tasty one.

Comment: You can use reference qualifiers to constrain your `operator =` etc.

Comment: Are move semantics really relevant for the return value of `operator=`?  I can't think of any case in well written code where they would be.  (One can construct artificial examples, but they wouldn't occur in well written code.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you may do instead of returning const element is to restrict the method to lvalue object:

```
struct S
{
    S& operator =(const S& rhs) & // note the final &
                                  // to restrict this to be lvalue
    {
        // implementation
        return *this;
    }
};
```

So with

```
S operator +(const S& lhs, const S& rhs);
S a, b, c;
```

The following is illegal:

```
(a + b) = c;
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/5Vumce)

Comment: Nitpick of the week: It's only *illegal* in a jurisdiction whose laws incorporate the C++11 standard. I know of none such, so you should probably say the code is *ill-formed*. Also, you should probably answer the duplicate instead of this question - it could use a recent answer.